# Detecting Heap corruption in windows

Tags: windows, heap-corruption

I am working on a 64 bit DLL called by Java. This makes using the debugger very difficult. It appears to corrupt the heap at some point, then crashes much latter. Is there some function that this dll can call to verify that the entire heap is not corrupted? I would like to make this call from critical places in the program and have it report any problems in some form.

Answer (score 0):

I found a function HeapWalk in the microsoft library which worked. When it did hit the error it went into a loop instead of returning an error but still it solved the problem.

The code is below. It is probably useless in its exact form but may give one the idea. It is called:

```
err=heap_check(__FILE__,__LINE__);

int heap_check(char *file,int line)
{//walks the heap to check for any errors
int return_val;
static HANDLE default_heap=NULL;
static int err_cnt=0;
static int entry_cnt=0;
clock_t start_time;
PROCESS_HEAP_ENTRY heap_entry;
return_val=0;
heap_entry.lpData=NULL;
if (err_cnt<100)
    {
    if ((entry_cnt %1000)==0)Printf("\n %s %d %d %d %s %d",__FILE__,__LINE__,err_cnt,entry_cnt,file,line);
    //Printf("\n");
    start_time=clock();
    if (default_heap==NULL)
        default_heap=GetProcessHeap();
    if (default_heap!=NULL)
        for (int ia=0,return_val=TRUE;ia<1000000 && return_val;ia++)
            {
            return_val=HeapWalk(default_heap,&heap_entry);
            //Printf(" %x",heap_entry.lpData);
            if ((ia%10000)==0)printf(" %d",ia);
            if (!return_val || ia==999999)
                {
                int err;
                err=GetLastError();
                if (err!=ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS)
                    {
                    Printf("\n %s %d  HEAP_ERROR %d cnt %d",file,line,err,ia);
                    err_cnt++;
                    }
                else 
                    if ((entry_cnt %1000)==0)Printf(" cnt %d %d",ia,clock()-start_time);
                }
            }
        else
            Printf("\n %s %d no heap handle",file,line);
    }
entry_cnt++;
return(return_val);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a Win32 function that will do this.

HeapValidate().

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/heapapi/nf-heapapi-heapvalidate

To check all heaps in your process:

```
HeapValidate(NULL, 0, NULL);
```

To check a specific heap in your process:

```
HeapValidate(hHeap, 0, NULL);
```

To check a specific allocation in a specific heap:

```
HeapValidate(hHeap, 0, ptr);
```